# DIV not covering whole content vertically

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The Wordpress theme I'm using offers a thing called Page Builder with which one can add different elements and fill them with stuff, for instance a heading, a content box, a gallery of pictures, videos, etc. Now, the problem is that if a Content box (basically something that should contain the main body of  text on a page) is filled with normal text, it's ok. But when I add a shortcode for a WP plugin, the output of the plugin is fine, but the div.blog-box which is supposed to provide the background of this content, does not actually appear.

Compare the two screenshots: the first one is text-only, the second one contains an output of a plugin shortcode.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

```
.blog-box {
padding: 10px 20px;
background: #fff;
margin-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
max-width: 1170px;
background: #333333;}
```

These are the styles that apply to the div. Can anyone help me find the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Have checked by inspecting element ? Second image that you posted, Is code of that wrapped in `.blog-box`? My guess it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use overflow:hidden;

```
.blog-box {
padding: 10px 20px;
background: #fff;
margin-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
max-width: 1170px;
background: #333333;
overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: Just tried your  suggestion. Overflow:hidden did the trick! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm sorry, but that just hides the problem: it doesn't fix it. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described, it seems the element your plugin is outputting must be floated with CSS (ie, `float:left`), because otherwise the `.blog-box` div should be taking the height of its children with the styles you have shared.
Try unfloating that child element see if it works:

```
.child-element {
    float:none;
}
```

Replace `child-element` with the CSS class of that element.

Comment: Indeed, unfloating the element results in the background appearing. However, that scrambles all the elements. :(

Comment: It would really help if you could post a link to the page displaying that content or reproduce it in a fiddle or code snippet.